# Android Alarm vibrate does not work

Tags: android, vibration

I have created AlarmReceiver class and I added there vibration function when alarm receives. In my code there must be some mistake because vibration does not start when alarm receives. This is a part of code :

```
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds


    }


    private Vibrator getSystemService(String vibratorService) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;

    }
}
```

Of course I added p`ermission` to `manifest`. Do I need to implement `getSystemService` to this code, if I don't implement this method then `eclipse` throws me an error that I need to implement this method.

Answer (score 1):

You don't nned to implemeet getSystemService. You need to caal it to get access to the Vibrator object, and then invoke the vibrate method over it.
You need, however, to cast the object returned by getSystemService to Vibrator.

```
Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator)context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
vibrator.vibrate(500});
```